# Format number price styles with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want format a number price after comma, with an smaller font:
[image]

For example, I have this span:

```
<span class="price">9,95€</span>
```

I need replace with something like:

```
<span class="price">9,<span class="small-price">95€</span></span>
```

How can I do it with javascript, php, or css?

Comment: Some advice: The Euro-sign must be placed before the value.

Comment: ^^ it depends on the culture.

Comment: It depends on the language. In English you write €42; in French and Italian it’s 42€.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below snippet we can do this using `regex`.

```js
$.each($('.price'), function() {
  var price = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(price.replace(/(\d*\,)(\d*)(\D*)/, '<span style="font-size:22px;">$1</span><span style="font-size:16px;">$2</span><span style="font-size:14px;">$3</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='price'>270,30€</div>
```

Comment: Please make some comments if you'r down voted any answer to figure out anyone what's wrong in their answer

Comment: This works to me. Mmm can you edit your answer with a example with php code using preg_replace() function?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
  var priceEl = prices[i];
  var price = priceEl.innerHTML;
  var priceParts = price.split(',');
  var smallPriceValue = priceParts[1];
  if (smallPriceValue) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = "small-price";
    span.innerHTML = smallPriceValue;
    priceEl.innerHTML = priceParts[0]+ ",";
    priceEl.appendChild(span);
  }
}
```

```css
.price {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.small-price {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">9,95€</span><br>
<span class="price">12,85€</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementsByClassName` and change the element with plain Javascript.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('price'), function (a) {
    a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/(\d\d€)/, '<span class="small-price">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.price { font-size: 36px; }
.small-price { font-size: 24px; }
```

```html
<span class="price">9,95€</span><br>
<span class="price">0,01€</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this in CSS, not that difficult

```css
.small-price {
  font-size: 7pt;
  }
```

```html
5,<font class="small-price">95</font>
```